# Python Dynamic Type Hints (like Dataclasses)

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

I have a dataclass, and a function which will create an instance of that dataclass using all the kwargs passed to it.
If I try to create an instance of that dataclass, I can see the type hints/autocomplete for the `__init__` method. I just need the similar type hints for a custom function that I want to create.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Model:
    attr1: str
    attr2: int


def my_func(**kwargs):
    model = Model(**kwargs)

    ...  # Do something else
    ret = [model]

    return ret

# my_func should show that it needs 'attr1' & 'attr2'
my_func(attr1='hello', attr2=65535)
```

Comment: If you know `my_func` requires `attr1` and `attr2`, put them in the parameter list explicitly.

Comment: Or, don't take the arguments needed by `Model` as arguments; take a pre-constructed instance of `Model` instead.

Comment: As of now, not yet. However it [may be available in the future](https://peps.python.org/pep-0692/).

Comment: This sounds similar to a question on inferring [init params](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73778158/10237506) for a dataclass that I had previously asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your IDE isn't sophisticated enough to infer that `kwargs` isn't used for anything else than to create a `Model` instance (I'm not sure if there is such an IDE), then it has no way of knowing that `attr1` and `attr2` are the required arguments, and the obvious solution would be to list them explicitly.

I would refactor the function so that it takes a `Model` instance as argument instead.

Then you would call it like `my_func(Model(...))` and the IDE could offer the autocompletion for `Model`.

Comment: Yeah, the current code is like this, but the problem was that there were a lot of different models from different files, so I was looking for a way to make it like this. @Axe319 mentioned that type hinting kwargs may be available in future